# Two instances of microSIP on the same Windows7

Tags: sip

I'm testing a Media Server and I need to make multiple SIP calls on the same time. I used microSIP but I failed to find how to launch it with multiple instances. Is any way to launch several instances of microSIP on the same Windows7?
Do you know any other sip client with multiple instances? Linphone doesn't works on my Windows7.

Answer (score 5):

Just copy MicroSIP folder to different folders locations and launch separately